# Correctly speeding up ball in breakout game on collision

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I have these 3 scripts in my assets (among others). My General Manager(GM), my ball and my crazybrick. When it touches the crazy brick its supposed to move a little faster each time. In my GM I set a boolean fastball equal to false and set it true on collision in my crazybrick script using a GM instance. Then in my ball script, if true, I incrementally make the ball go faster then set fastball back to false. I test this with debug logs and it goes 100f faster every time. All seems perfect on the first test. But with subsequent tests weird things happen. The ball sometime goes slower, or shoots out of my walls after getting faster too quickly or doesn't seem to get faster at all. Its always different. Below is my relevant code for the three scripts.

```
public class GM : MonoBehaviour {
 public bool fastBall = false;
 public static GM instance = null;
}


public class CrazyBrick : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject brickParticle;

    void OnCollisionEnter ()
    {
        GM.instance.fastBall = true;
        Instantiate (brickParticle, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        GM.instance.DestroyBrick ();
        Destroy (gameObject);
    }
}


public class Ball : MonoBehaviour {


    public float ballInitialVelocity = 600f;
    public float newVelocity;
    private Rigidbody rb;
    private bool ballInPlay;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Awake () {

        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate () {
        if (GM.instance.fastBall) {

            newVelocity = newVelocity + 100f;
            Debug.Log ("increment 100f: " + newVelocity);
            rb.AddForce(new Vector3(newVelocity, newVelocity, 0));

            GM.instance.fastBall = false;

        }
        if(Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1") && ballInPlay == false)
        {

            transform.parent = null;
            ballInPlay = true;
            rb.isKinematic = false;
            rb.AddForce(new Vector3(ballInitialVelocity, ballInitialVelocity, 
            0));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know the exact velocity you want the rigid body set to then you can just set the velocity directly instead of calling `AddForce`. On top of that you're calling `AddForce` and adding the full velocity plus the 100 units. So if you had a velocity of 50, you're then calculating 150 and calling addforce with that, giving you 50 + 150, instead of just giving you 150. If you want to call `AddForce` then you should add 100.

Also, if you add equal force along X and Y, which you're doing, then that's actually more than the original amount. If you think about the pythagorean theorem, the hypotenuse of a right triangle is longer than the other two sides. So if you're adding 100 to X and 100 to Y, that's actually approximately 141 units per second you'll be adding. You should get the velocity direction, and add 100 units along that direction, this avoids the issue of adding along multiple vectors and then having to normalize that value.

Try something like this in the places you're using `rb.AddForce()`:

```
// Get the current velocity vector
var oldVelocity = rb.velocity;

// Get the current speed
var oldMagnitude = oldVelocity.magnitude;

// Get the current direction the rigid body is moving in
var direction = oldVelocity.normalized;

// The new velocity is in the same direction but faster than before
var newVelocity = direction * (oldMagnitude + 100f);

// Set the rigid body to the new velocity
rb.velocity = newVelocity;
```

Maybe this would work for you:

```
void FixedUpdate () {
    if (GM.instance.fastBall) {

        // Get the current velocity vector
        var oldVelocity = rb.velocity;

        // Get the current speed
        var oldMagnitude = oldVelocity.magnitude;

        // Get the current direction the rigid body is moving in
        var direction = oldVelocity.normalized;

        // The new velocity is in the same direction but faster than before
        var newVelocity = direction * (oldMagnitude + 100f);

        // Set the rigid body to the new velocity
        rb.velocity = newVelocity;

        GM.instance.fastBall = false;
    }
    if(Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1") && ballInPlay == false)
    {
        transform.parent = null;
        ballInPlay = true;
        rb.isKinematic = false;

        // Get the current direction the rigid body is moving in
        var direction = oldVelocity.normalized;

        rb.velocity = direction * ballInitialVelocity;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok so I'm adding your example and Im assuming .magnitude and .normalized is part of Vector3, but it doesnt recognize it.

Comment: That's strange, they're documented here: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.html

More specifically, here: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-normalized.html

And here: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-magnitude.html

Comment: yeah I saw that too, but its highlighted in red in unity and says system.single does not contain a definition for magnitude

Comment: You should be dealing with a Vector3 rather than a Single. rb.velocity should be returning a Vector3. I would change 'var oldVelocity' to 'Vector3 oldVelocity' and see if that gives you a compile error. Also, I could verify that 'rb' is indeed a UnityEngine.RigidBody.

Comment: Ok so after getting rid of all the errors and testing it the ball doesnt leave the paddle on playing so Im thinking that without the addforce, nothing happens

Comment: I've personally never needed AddForce() using Unity. Setting velocity has always worked for me. You'll need to debug and see what the direction vector and velocity vector is that you're using to set on the rigidbody. If they're non-zero then there may be another issue stopping the movement.

Comment: ok I ended up tagging the balls and looping though, using this in my GM which worked, thanks